# Sql Server - Using Collation

Tags: sql-server, collation

I am using below query in which I need to specify collation hint to avoid collation issues across databases as this query uses tables from 2 databases.

> Msg 468, Level 16, State 9, Line 12 Cannot resolve the collation
>   conflict between "Latin1_General_CS_AI" and "Latin1_General_CS_AS" in
>   the equal to operation.

Currently I am getting above error for collation conflicts when I run some of the queries which uses different databases with different collations:

```
Delete from table1 where oldcolumn in
(
select newcolumn from Database2.dbo.table2
where invoiceid = @invno
and complete = 0
)
```

I changed the query to include collation hint as below:

```
Delete from table1 where oldcolumn COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS in
(
select newcolumn from Database2.dbo.table2
where invoiceid = @invno
and complete = 0
)
```

1. Will above query solve the problem of collation?
2. Is it same to specify collate hint on left or right of operator (e.g. "=" operator)?
3. Can query like `invoiceid = @invno` ever generate runtime collation conflit error?

**Note:** I am asking this question as I do not have access to any of the above 2 databases and the script will be run on actual databases.

Comment: You forget to describe "the problem of the collation" you're experiencing now. Are you getting an error message, wrong results or what?

Comment: I am getting runtime error for collation conflict. I have updated question.

Comment: You forgot to post the error message.

Comment: Which column has which collation? Do you need `oldcolumn = 'resume'` to be deleted when `newcolumn = 'résumé'` is returned from `table2` or vice versa?

Comment: Please do not go with values. I am only concerned about runtime error at the moment.

Comment: Which type are `invoiceid` and `@invno`?

Comment: See [Collation Precedence](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179886.aspx). Should answer all your questions I think.

Answer (score 0):

Use Below Query :

```
DELETE FROM Table1
WHERE Table1.ID IN (
                SELECT Table1.ID
                FROM Table1
                INNER JOIN Database2.dbo.Table2 Table2 ON Table2.NewColumn = Table1.OldColumn COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS
                WHERE   Table2.invoiceid = @invno
                    AND Table2.complete = 0
                )
```